# TF2.3 - More model outputs than targets

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to write a model in which there are three outputs, the latter two of which are to be trained with respect to targets present in the dataset, the former should just be a non-trainable output.

First, defining a dataset:

```py
from typing import Tuple

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def ds_fn(in_shape: Tuple[int],
          out_shape: Tuple[int],
          dtype: tf.DType = tf.float32) -> tf.data.Dataset:
  # Generator function.
  def gen() -> Tuple[Tuple[np.array], Tuple[np.array]]:
    for _ in range(1000):
      # Inputs.
      x0 = np.ones(in_shape, dtype=np.float32)
      x1 = 2 * x0

      # Outputs.
      y0 = np.ones(out_shape, dtype=np.float32)
      y1 = 2 * np.ones_like(y0)
      y2 = 3 * np.ones_like(y1)

      # Targets correspond to outputs 1 and 2 of the network. Output 0 has
      # no target.
      yield (x0, x1), (y1, y2)

  return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen,
                                        output_types=((dtype,) * 2, # Input
                                                      (dtype,) * 2), # Output
                                        output_shapes=((in_shape,) * 2, # Input
                                                       (out_shape,) * 2)) # Output
```

In the above, the dataset has two targets, corresponding to the last two outputs of the model defined below.

```py
from tensorflow import keras

class ExampleModel(keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, out_dim: int):
    super().__init__()

    self.dense_a = keras.layers.Dense(out_dim)
    self.dense_b = keras.layers.Dense(out_dim)

  def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    a, b = inputs

    x0 = self.dense_a(a)
    x1 = self.dense_b(b)

    x = (x0 + x1) / 2

    return (x, # Output 0 - should not be trained.
            2 * x,
            3 * x)
```

From reading the Keras documentation, to handle this case where there are a greater number of model outputs than there are targets in the dataset (with the surplus outputs considered to be non-trainable), it appears that the `Model.compile` arg `loss_weights` should handle the matching between targets and losses. More concretely, given the following.

```py
def model_fn(out_dim: int) -> ExampleModel:

  m = ExampleModel(out_dim)

  losses = [
    None, # Output 0 - should not be trainable.
    'mse',
    'mse'
  ]

  loss_weights = [
    0, # Output 0 - should not be trainable.
    1,
    1
  ]

  m.compile(loss=losses,
            loss_weights=loss_weights,
            optimizer='sgd')

  return m
```

I would expect that Keras would disregard the first model output when computing the loss, given the `None` loss provided and the `0` loss weight, however I am seeing the following error.

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same sequence length. Input structure has length 2, while shallow structure has length 3.
```

Which seems to indicate that this is not the case when run as follows.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
  bs = 16
  in_dim = 4
  out_dim = 8
  epochs = 10

  ds = ds_fn((bs, 1, in_dim), (bs, 1, out_dim))
  ds = ds.repeat(epochs)

  m = model_fn(out_dim)

  m.fit(ds,
        epochs=epochs,
        batch_size=bs)
```

If I provide an additional target in `data_fn` and `gen`, combined with a dummy loss (`lambda x, y: 0.0`. for example), then training commences. However, this will not scale to a non toy problem with potentially large outputs and targets (images, for example).

If I instead return a `dict` from the model `call` method and provide `dict` for `losses` and `loss_weights` (both with keys matching that returned from `call`), there is no change (I thought that the explicit output naming might allow Keras to match outputs, losses and targets).

Am I misunderstanding the intended purpose of lists as `losses` (in which `None` is allowed) and `loss_weights`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way could be to create a dictionary mapping dataset and model and later use the key of that dictionary to control the loss, metrics (and relevant) parameters. Here is how it can be done.

**Data**

```py
def ds_fn(
    in_shape: Tuple[int],
    out_shape: Tuple[int],
    dtype: tf.DType = tf.float32
) -> tf.data.Dataset:
  # Generator function.
    def gen() -> Tuple[Tuple[np.array], Tuple[np.array]]:
        for _ in range(1000):
            # Inputs.
            x0 = np.ones(in_shape, dtype=np.float32)
            x1 = 2 * x0

            # Outputs.
            y0 = np.ones(out_shape, dtype=np.float32)
            y1 = 2 * np.ones_like(y0)
            y2 = 3 * np.ones_like(y1)

            # Targets correspond to outputs 1 and 2 of the network. Output 0 has
            # no target.
            yield {'input_a': x0, 'input_b': x1}, {'output_a': y1, 'output_b': y2}

    return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        gen,
        output_types=(
            {'input_a': dtype, 'input_b': dtype},
            {'output_a': dtype, 'output_b': dtype}
        ),
        output_shapes=(
            {'input_a': in_shape, 'input_b': in_shape},
            {'output_a': out_shape, 'output_b': out_shape}
        )
    )
```

**Model**

```py
class ExampleModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, out_dim: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense_a = keras.layers.Dense(out_dim)
        self.dense_b = keras.layers.Dense(out_dim)

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        x0 = self.dense_a(inputs['input_a'])
        x1 = self.dense_b(inputs['input_b'])
        x = (x0 + x1) / 2
        return {
            "output_a": x, 
            "output_b": 2 * x,
            "output_c": 3 * x
        }
```

**Compile**

```py
def model_fn(out_dim: int) -> ExampleModel:
    m = ExampleModel(out_dim)

    losses = {
        "output_b": 'mse',
        "output_c": 'mse'
    }

    loss_weights = {
        "output_a": 1,
        "output_b": 1
    }

    m.compile(
        loss=losses,
        loss_weights=loss_weights,
        optimizer='sgd'
    )
    
    return m
```

**Run**

```py
m = model_fn(out_dim)

m.fit(
    ds,
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=bs
)

loss: 3.2685e-13 - output_b_loss: 3.2685e-13 - output_c_loss: 0.0000e+00
```

**Additional Resource**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75601418/9215780
2. [Segmentation Modeling into Classifier Model](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ipythonx/keras-segmentation-modeling-into-classifier-model)

Comment: This approach is closest to my use case, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand the question, using the functional API of keras you could have something like this after defining the inputs and outputs:

```
loss1 = mse(y, output1)
loss2 = mae(y, output2)

final_loss = [loss1, loss2]

model.add_loss(final_loss)

a = 0.9

alpha = K.variable(a)
beta = K.variable(1-a)

model.compile(
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
loss_weights=[alpha, beta]
)
```

Here we wrap the two losses as a list and then add the two weights (alpha and beta) corresponding to the list's elements.

I think you might be able to run this after creating the model object, but you might have to do some tweaks for it to run properly.

Therefore, there won't be any need for this dummy None type loss and its additional 0 weight.

I hope this helps!

EDIT: making small corrections. I misunderstood your initial notation. I have made the two losses different just to illustrate the possibilities.